# How to register channel on local machine to be accessible from the Internet?

Tags: c#, tcp, remote-access

I am running console application (server side) that uses tcp and a specific port for incoming connections.

```
TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(XXXX);
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(YYYYService), "ZZZZMethod", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

How can I allow access this service from the Internet without forwarding port in my router?
Is there any chance to get a public IP and connect to a specific service running on a local machine?
Like chat or remote control programs do..

Comment: Many chat programs are not peer to peer, they send to a central server which broadcasts it to other chat members. TeamViewer (remote control software) uses port 80 by default, which HTTP traffic comes through, meaning no port forwarding.

Comment: But if you have 2 pcs in your network you can run teamviewer on each pc and work remote on each one of them at the same time, right?

Comment: Ah that is true I think, I'm not really an expert on this though, just my 2 cents.

Comment: I guess there is something with uPnP but I am trying to get how exactly it works.

Comment: I am using right now [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27992/NAT-Traversal-with-UPnP-in-C#xx4718439xx) from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265367/how-to-access-server-within-local-network-from-internet). When I run my console app it shows my app in Current UPnP Settings List of my router on a remote pc. However I still cannot connect the remote pc.